# CakePHP3: Generate DB-Query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm new to CakePHP and I would like to query locations in my DB depending on Google Maps Lat & Lng. How can I add the two `andWhere` statements only, if `$params['bounds']` is true?

```
$params = [
    'bounds' => 1,
    'swLat' => ...,
    'swLng' => ...,
    'neLat' => ...,
    'neLng' => ...
];

$locations = $this->Locations
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'lat', 'lng'])
    ->where(['live' => 1])
    ->andWhere(function ($exp, $q) {
          return $exp->between('lat', $params['swLat'], $params['neLat']);
    })
    ->andWhere(function ($exp, $q) {
          return $exp->between('lng', $params['swLng'], $params['neLng']);
    })
    ->order(['name' => 'ASC']);
```

Comment: If you surround code in-line with backticks, they will be represented in code font. Also, no need to add thanks or your name to the bottom of the question.

Comment: By using an `if` statement and only calling these methods in case the condition is true?

Comment: @AlBlue: Sorry, I've added my name with a warm thank you for answers below the code, but strangely it's not visible in my question. Perhaps I messed up someting with the code block.

Comment: @ndm: But where can I add the if-statement in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add the two andWhere statements only, if $params['bounds'] is true?

The query methods are intended to be used (as demonstrated by the question) using a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP); this means each method returns the `$this` object.

So to add conditional logic, first do the unconditional calls:

```
$locations = $this->Locations->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'lat', 'lng'])
    ->where(['live' => 1])
    ->order(['name' => 'ASC']);
```

And then apply whatever other calls you wish:

```
if (!empty($params['bounds'])) {
    $locations
        ->andWhere(function ($exp, $q) use ($params) {
          return $exp
              ->between('lat', $params['swLat'], $params['neLat']);
              ->between('lng', $params['swLng'], $params['neLng']);
        })
}
```

Note that for `$params` to be accessible inside the closure passed to `andWhere` - it's necessary to use [the use language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Unlike some languages (most notably javascript) functions *do not* automatically have access to variables in the parent scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok, I understand. But why does `$params['swLat']` etc. inside the addWhere-function return NULL? Or in other words: If I am inside the addWhere-function, how can I access a variable which is outside definied?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Hmm, you see, I'm unexperienced with PHP and new to CakePHP and OOP. Normally I query all locations inside the DB but if the user choses the option "only inside the viewport" (Google Maps API) I would like to display only locations inside the viewport. Is there a possibility to access the variable from the parent scope? Or how would you build the query?

Comment: If I replace `$params['swLat']` with `$this->request->data['swLat']` it works but if I do so, how can I validate the data before insert into the query?

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify, in future if there's a problem with the code in the question (that's not directly related to what you're asking), _please mention it_.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks, AD7six. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow too... :)

Comment: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work